# Not able to load weights after fine tuning the model with VGG16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have loaded the weights from VGG16 and added to my Sequential Model. I want to train the lower weights of VGG16 by freezing the top layers (Fine Tuning).

Everything was good: I was able to build the model and predict new images. But now I want to load the model, which I was unable to do.

This is what I have tried shown as following code:

```
model1 = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', 
include_top=False,input_shape=(img_width,img_height,3))

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   rotation_range=40,
                                   width_shift_range=0.2,
                                   height_shift_range=0.2,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   fill_mode='nearest')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


 train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                                        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                        batch_size=size_batch, 
                                        class_mode='binary', 
                                        shuffle=False) 


# repeat with the validation data

 test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir,
                                       target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                       batch_size=size_batch,
                                       class_mode='binary',
                                       shuffle=False)


 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Flatten(input_shape=model1.output_shape[1:]))
 model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dropout(0.2))
 model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

 new_model=Sequential()

 for l in model1.layers:
      new_model.add(l)

  new_model.add(model)

 for layer in new_model.layers[:25]:
       layer.trainable=False

 new_model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-3, 
 momentum=0.9),loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
 checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(fine_tuned_model_path, monitor='val_acc', 
                             verbose=1, save_best_only=True, 
                             save_weights_only=False, mode='auto')
# fine-tune the model
fit=new_model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                          steps_per_epoch=33,
                          nb_epoch=1,

                          validation_data=test_generator,

                          verbose=1,callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

I then was trying to load the model:

```
load_model("C:/Users/hi/POC/Fine_Tune/model.h5")
```

This is the error I am receiving:

> ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 14 layers
>   into a model with 1 layers.

Comment: please post your whole code if it is not very long.

Comment: Hi FessianXu , i have added the code

Comment: Hi Esskay, Please print the network architecture :  `new_model.summary()`. I doubt that the new_model might not built as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

According to Keras issue [8898](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8998#issuecomment-355956971), this error can be avoided by editing the Keras code `keras/applications/vgg16.py`

so that the line(s) that used to read
`model.load_weights(weights_path)` now read `model.load_weights(weights_path, by_name=True)`

I have found this to work for imagenet weights with other Applications models as well, e.g. nasnet.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks @sh37211

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you had to define a new model and load the previous layers of VGG16 into your new model.

The best work around that l would advice is freezing the layer of the VGG16 
   architecture you want and have the ones you want as trainable layers, as you did in the last `for` loop

This will ultimately result in you removing the two `for` loops you have 
   embedded inside.

```
# the way you loaded your images and did not include_top layer 
model1 = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3))

#to see the structure of your architecture
model.summary() 

#freezing the layers you do not want for training in your architecture
for layer in model1.layers[:25]:
    layer.trainable = False

#the rest is the same from here on forth with the exclusion of the two for loops
#which you need to remove as they are no longer required.
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                               rotation_range=40,
                               width_shift_range=0.2,
                               height_shift_range=0.2,
                               shear_range=0.2,
                               zoom_range=0.2,
                               horizontal_flip=True,
                               fill_mode='nearest')

#etc...
```

Comment: I have added new model because the pre trained VGG model which I am loading is of 'Model' type and the model which i am using is 'Sequential '  model. So, Iam unable to use it.So i have created a new model and added those pre trained layers using  for loop.